# Вставка столбца в определенное место DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe

Есть способ завести новую переменную `Mydata$new_var <- ...`,  но проблема в том, что она записывается в конец DataFrame'а.
Как сделать, чтобы стала в определенный столбец?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `add_column()` из стандартной библиотеки `tibble`.

```
library(tibble)
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- c(4, 5, 6)
c <- c(7, 8, 9)
d <- c(10, 20, 30)
dt <- data.frame(a, b, c)

> dt
  a b c
1 1 4 6
2 2 5 7
3 3 6 8
```

Для того, чтобы добавить столбец в определённую позицию используем `add_column`

```
dt <- add_column(dt, d, .after = 1)
> dt
  a  d b c
1 1 10 4 6
2 2 20 5 7
3 3 30 6 8
```

В качестве аргументов передаётся исходный датафрейм и вектор, который нужно добавить. При помощи агрументов `.before` или `.after` указывают позицию (номер или наименование), до или после какого столбца необходимо вставить новый столбец.

```
 add_column(dt, d, .after = 1) # вставить после 1-го столбца
 add_column(dt, d, .before = 3) # вставить перед 3-м столбцом
 add_column(dt, d, .before = "b") # вставить перед столбцом b
```

**UPD.** Просто поменять столбцы местами

```
 dt <- dt[, c("b", "c", "a")]
 > dt
   b c a
 1 4 6 1
 2 5 7 2
 3 6 8 3
```

В векторе указываем порядок столбцов, например, `c("b", "c", "a")` -- первым будет идти столбец `"b"`, вторым -- столбец `"c"`, третьим -- столбец `"a"`.

Comment: Здорово, спасибо! Жаль вот только, что это не реализовано на уровне base.

Comment: И еще маленький вопрос, если он конечно не требует отдельного обсуждения: Как можно менять столбцы местами, например? По идее это более общий вопрос, но вдруг на него есть простой ответ.

Comment: Добавил небольшое дополнение в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: В `base` есть функция `append`, которая позволяет указать позиция вставки. В `data.table` есть функция `setcolorder`, которая позволяет изменить порядок столбцов без перезаписи объектов в памяти и создания ненужных копий объектов.